# Make javascript ignore a piece of code

Tags: javascript

How can you purposely make javascript ignore a piece of code. That is:
if you have something like this:

```
function hello() { console.log('hello'); }
```

Is there a way to make javascript ignore this and not create a function name `hello`? Can this be done in pure javascript?

Comment: either remove that or comment that out :P

Comment: Don't define a function you don't want to call. Or you can overwrite the variable afterwards: `hello = null; ` or `delete hello `.

Comment: Just delete it. I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: Why declaring the function if you don't want to use it?

Comment: maybe a piece of code which has different syntax and later on will be manipulated and run, in the mean time, ignore the function fo there will be no syntax error

Comment: [Is it possible to tell Node/Deno to ignore a portion of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76737880/3416774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override that function to do nothing, for example:

```
hello = function(){}
```

**UPDATE**

As i saw in your comment. You only want to ignore this code but still want to use it later. So I think you might want to try this:

1- Save the function pointer

```
var oldHello = hello;
```

2- Override it

```
hello = function() {}
```

3- Restore for later use

```
hello = oldHello;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another approach, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can't remove or comment out that code, no, you can't prevent the function from being created.

You *can*, though, disconnect the function from the `hello` symbol:

```
hello = undefined;
```

Now you can't call the function via that symbol anymore, and if it was the only reference to the function, the function is eligible for GC.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/IGUKIHu/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IGUKIHu/1/edit)

```
function hello() { console.log("Hello"); }

console.log("Before setting <code>hello = undefined;</code>");
try {
    hello();
}
catch (e1) {
    console.log("Exception on 'before' call: " + (e1.message || String(eq)));
}

hello = undefined;

console.log("After setting <code>hello = undefined;</code>");
try {
    hello();
}
catch (e2) {
    console.log("Exception on 'after' call: " + (e2.message || String(eq)));
}
```

Output:

```
Before setting hello = undefined;
Hello
After setting hello = undefined;
Exception on 'after' call: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: what about an object? I want to ignore the object an any code relate to it and its properties/methods

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to wrap it in a `if` that checks for dev/prod environment:

```js
try {
    //calling an object or function that is only available in the product
} catch (error) {
    var isOnIDE = true
}
if (!isOnIDE ) {
    //product code
```

If you want to control this manually, try:

```js
function main(mode='production') {
    if (mode === 'debug' || mode === 1) {
        // debug code
    } else {
        // product code
    }
} 

main('debug')
```

While you still have to edit the `mode` variable when pasting to the platform, at least you don't have to comment and uncomment repeatedly.