# JavaScript: Ignore Function from script.js on Specific Page

Tags: javascript

I have a `script.js` file linked to all of the pages on my site.

On only one page in particular, the "About" page, I don't want a certain function from `script.js`, called `myFunction`, to run, because it messes with the formatting on that page.

However, I do still need to use the rest of the JS from `script.js` on this page, so I don't want to unlink the `script.js` file and copy every single line of code from `script.js` except `myFunction` onto the About page locally, as then I will need to update that page manually every time I add new JS to the `script.js` file.

Is there a way to tell a specific page to ignore a certain function from `script.js`? I thought this would be easy to find an answer to but all I could find were results for doing this in WordPress with php.

I would like to use vanilla JS if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001398/12684693

Comment: add an if(page != about) { myFunction();}

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, @flakerimi! For the "about" part of your code, would I replace that with the page url, like "about.html"?

Comment: can you put some code on question how you are trying to do it

Comment: you can get path with https://js-tricks.info/javascript/how-to-get-current-url-path-in-javascript/

Comment: @flakerimi my setup is pretty simple, ```script.js``` and ```about.html``` are within the same folder, so would I just use a relative url path, ```about.html```? Or do I need to use the full url, like ```https://www.urlhere.com/about.html```?

Comment: It does not matter, use what ever you want, to get full or relative, then make `if(relative or full != about) { ... continue function }` at start of  myFunction.

Comment: Thanks @iKiK! Will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code where you call your function on script.js

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 

if(pathname != 'about.html'){
  myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much @flakerimi!